# Find the cosets of $H$ in $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

$A_5$ is just the alternating group, i.e. the even permutation subgroup of $S_5$.

$H=\langle(12345)\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_5$.

I know there are exactly 12 different cosets of $H$ in $A_5$, but I have no idea how to write out them with a simple way.

Is there a simple method to determine these 12 different cosets without writing out all the elements $\alpha H$, for every $\alpha\in A_5?$

Thanks a lot :)

**Update:**

**@Derek has given a method to find all the different representatives of cosets of such $H$(i.e. $H=\langle(12345)\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_5$) in $A_5$.**

**But his method fails when $H=\langle(123),(12)(45)\rangle \cong S_3$. I have a try to find similar method, but I fails. So this problem is still open, for the case $H=\langle(123),(12)(45)\rangle \cong S_3$.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, many of the $\alpha H$ will overlap for the different $\alpha\in A_5$. You only have to use $12$ different $\alpha$'s. So that makes the list $5$ times shorter, at least.

Comment: @lanskey Ahh sorry... I have fixed it.

Comment: @Arthur Yes you are right. But is there a systematic method to find such 12 different $\alpha 's$? I think there must be some method. But I don't know it... Could you tell me such method?

Comment: @Arthur If there is no a guiding method, we just try and try, and then the worst case is that we need to try 60 times... right...?

Comment: I misunderstood. Yes, you're right. Without a guiding principle, you would have to write out all $60$ of them to be able to check against any you already have. Or, at least, $56$ of them. I was a bit further ahead, and was thinking about after that, when you write down all the cosets you found as the answer to the problem.

Comment: There is a very easy way of doing this. Just write down the $12$ elements of $A_5$ that fix some specific point, say $5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I think it should work, because the order of $A_4$ is exactly $12$. But I am going to sleep, I will check it tomorrow. Could you explain the reason why it works behind this? I think maybe I can get to know the reason during the process I check tomorrow. But I am longing to know it now... And my second problem is that, if $H=<(123),(12)(45)>\cong S_3$, how we proceed now? The method seems failing. Thank you so much Derek :)

Comment: @Arthur It's fine. Derek has given a method for this specific $H$. :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a slick method for the subgroup  $\langle (1,2,3),(1,2)(4,5) \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no magic formula for writing down coset representatives. There are of course computer algorithms used by software such as GAP and Magma, and they use a variety of technical ideas to reduce the search space. I won't go into that in any detail here.

But by applying some of the ideas used in the algorithms, I managed to write down left coset reps of the subgroup $\langle (1,2,3),(1,2)(4,5) \rangle$ of $A_5$ without too much difficulty or calculation.

The stabilizer of the point $1$ in $H$ is the subgroup $\langle (2,3)(4,5) \rangle$, so I started by writing down $6$ coset reps of that in $A_4$. That was not too hard, and I took $1$, $(2,4)(3,5)$, $(2,3,4)$, $(2,4,3)$, $(2,3,5)$, $(2,5,3)$.

We can take the other reps from permutations mapping $1$ to $4$ or $5$. I noticed that the three elements $(1,4)(2,3)$, $(1,4)(2,5)$ and $(1,4)(3,5)$ all lie in different cosets from the $6$ already chosen and from each other,
so now we have $9$.

I was afraid the final one might be hard to find, but then I noticed that $(1,5)(2,3)$ is not in any of the other cosets, so we are done.

Comment: In your first step, the subgroup $\langle (2,3)(4,5)\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_2$ right? What’s the relation between the $6$ reps you chose and this subgroup? I cannot figure it out. Could you explain it? Thanks Derek.

Comment: $\langle (2,3)(4,5) \rangle$ is the stabilizer $H_1$ of $1$ in $H$. It has order $2$. The stabilizer of $1$ in $G=A_5$ is $A_4$, which has order $12$. So $H_1$ has index $6$ in $G_1$, and the six coset reps of $H_1$ in $G_1$ lie in different cosets of $H$ in $G$, so we can use use those as the first $6$ of our coset reps. The idea is we solve the problem first in a smaller group, i.e. in the stabilizer $G_1$. That's how the computer algorithms work.

Comment: Hi Derek, sorry for late reply. I still have two questions about this process. Q1: Why the six coset reps of $H_1$ in $G_1$ can induce six different cosets of $H$ in $G$?(I guess this problem is related to some propositions of stabilizer, but I cannot figure it out).  Q2: I got your idea. But we can not avoid computing repeat reps right? For example, when we find the six reps of $H_1$ in $G_1$, we have to compute $12$ cosets in order to find these six reps, right? These are my two questions. Thanks.

Comment: In general, if $H \le G$ and $K$ is some other subgroup of $G$ (in this case $K$ is the stabilizer), and $g,h \in K$, then $g,h$ are in distinct cosets of $H$ in $G$ if and only if they are in distinct cosets of $H \cap K$ in $K$. Question 2 seems to be identical to your original question. As I said, there is no magic formula method for finding coset representatives, and you cannot hope to avoid some repetition, but we can try.